# React Native: navigation.goBack() returns to other createStackNavigator screen instead of previous screen

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have multiple `createStackNavigator`. If I used the different `routeName` from other `createStackNavigator` it doesn't bring me back to the previous screen of current `createStackNavigator` am using, instead it returns back but its replaced to other `createStackNavigator` which causing me trouble to my UI. Is it possible to return to previous screen of that stack? Or its necessary to recreate required screens instead?

**AssetDashboardStack**

```
const ViewAssetDashBoardStack = createStackNavigator({
  ViewAssetsOnDashboard: {
    screen: ViewAssetsOnDashboard
  },
  ViewMapScreenFromdashboard: {
    screen: ViewMapScreen
  },
  ViewAssetDashboardOnScreen: {
    screen: ViewAssetsOnDashboard
  }
},
{
  transitionConfig: () => fromBottom(300),
  headerMode: "none",
  cardStyle: {backgroundColor: "#F0F4F5"},
  navigationOptions: {
    header:null
  }
}
);
```

**MapStack**

```
const MapStack = createStackNavigator({
  ViewMapScreen: {
    screen: ViewMapScreen
  },
  ViewMapSettings: {
    screen: ViewMapSettings
  },
  MapTypeScreen:{
    screen: MapTypeScreen
  },
  ViewAssetDetails: {
    screen: ViewAssetsOnDashboard
  },
  ViewZones: { // don't remove this is for viewing under map stack
    screen: Zones
  },
  HistorySelectionStack
},{
  transitionConfig:()=>fromRight(300),
  headerMode: "none",
  cardStyle: {backgroundColor: "#F0F4F5"},
  navigationOptions: {
    header:null
  }
});
```

Comment: please provide more information

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you have not defined/declared destination(class where you are moving back) screen in the same stack navigator.

Make sure to define/declare/add both screens in the same stack navigator. This is very simple and will be fixed by following above mentioned steps/instructions.

```
const stackNavigator1 = createStackNavigator(   {
    Home: { screen: Home },
    Chat: { screen: Chat },
    Camera: { screen: Camera },
    ChatCameraView: { screen: ChatCameraView },   },

const ChatListNavigator = createStackNavigator(   {
    ChatList: { screen: ChatList },
    Chat: { screen: Chat },
    ChatCameraView: { screen: ChatCameraView },   },
```

When user will navigate to Chat screen from Home screen and press back button, he will be navigated back to home screen as I have defined chat screen in the stackNavigator1, otherwise it will also have same issue you are facing.